# Filter Observable by Observable

Tags: javascript, frp, rxjs

I want to make sure that `Observable.subscribe()` doesn't get executed if a different Observable yields `true`.

An example use case would be making sure that user can trigger a download only if the previous one has finished (or failed) and there's only one download request executed at a time.

In order to control the execution flow, I had to rely on a state variable which seems a bit odd to me - is this a good pattern? In a v. likely case that it isn't - what would be a better approach?

I ended up with two subscriptions: `Actions.sync` (using a Subject, public API, initialises a sync request) and `isActive` (resolves to `true` or `false, the name should be pretty self-explanatory.

```
let canDownload = true; // this one feels really, really naughty
const startedSyncRequests = new Rx.Subject();
const isActiveSync = startedSyncRequests.map(true)
  .merge(completeSyncRequests.map(false))
  .merge(failedSyncRequests.map(false))
  .startWith(false)
  .subscribe(isActive => canDownload = !isActive)

syncResources = ()=>{
  startedSyncRequests.onNext();
  // Mocked async job
  setTimeout(()=> {
    completeSyncRequests.onNext();
  }, 1000);
};


Actions.sync
  .filter( ()=> canDownload ) // so does this
  .subscribe( syncResources );
```

Comment: Do you want queue the intermediate download requests?

Answer (score 2):

You want `exclusive()`.

```
Actions.sync
  .map(() => {
    //Return a promise or observable
    return Rx.Observable.defer(() => makeAsyncRequest());
  })
  .exclusive()
  .subscribe(processResults);
```

The above will generate an observable every time the user makes a request. However, `exclusive` will drop any observables that come in before the previous one has completed, and then flattens the resulting messages into a single observable.

Working example (using `interval` and `delay`):

```js
var interval = Rx.Observable.interval(1000).take(20);


interval
  .map(function(i) {
    return Rx.Observable.return(i).delay(1500);
  })
  .exclusive()
  //Only prints every other item because of the overlap
  .subscribe(function(i) {
    var item = $('<li>' + i + '</li>');
    $('#thelist').append(item);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/2.5.3/rx.all.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul id="thelist">
  </ul>

</div>
```

Reference: [here](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/src/core/linq/observable/exclusive.js)

Comment: How to handle if we want to queue intermediate download requests?

Comment: @SamarPanda use `concatAll()` instead of `exclusive()`